# The difficulty of generate complex Hadamard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A complex $n\times n$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ is called a Hadamard matrix if $A^{+}A=nI$ and $|a_{ij}|=1$ holds for all $i,j$, where $A^{+}$ denotes the conjugate transposed matrix of  $A$, and a vector $x=(x_1,x_2.....x_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$ is called unit if $|x_i|=1$ holds for all $i$.

For $n>5$, are there $d\times n$ matrix $F=[f_{ij}]$ which satisfies the following properties:

1. $FF^{+}=dI$,
2. $|f_{ij}|=1$ , holds for all $i,j$,
3. there is no unit vector $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ satisfies $F x^{+}=0$.

Which can be regarded as the difficulty of generate complex Hadamard matrix, actually, it is wanted to show the following method to find a complex Hadamard matrix does not always work:

Let $S$ be an empty set, choose a unit vector $x$  which is orthogonal to all the elements in $S$, and put $x$ in $S$, until there is no unit vector which orthogonal to all elements in $S$. Now what we ask can be regarded as is it possible that the algorithm stops but $|S|< n$.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question?

Comment: My take: are there dxn matrices which look like submatrices of an nxn complex Hadamard matrix, but actually are not?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.11.04

Comment: Exactly as what you said.

Comment: Despite Gerhard's best efforts, I still don't understand what's being asked. Perhaps it's time for MO to hire a full-time mindreader, fluent in mathematics. 

Comment: The latest edit is helpful, but I wonder whether in condition 3 you really only want $x$ to be a unit vector, which just means a vector of length 1. In the previous edit, you asked for all the components of $x$ to have modulus 1, a very different thing. The way you have it now, I think it's trivial that there is no such $F$. 

Comment: The definition of "unit" is given in the opening sentence, but it's not the usual one. Since there seems to be no standard term for a vector with unimodular elements, it would probably be clearer just to spell it out. Also, the condition d<n seems to have gotten deleted in the latest edit.

Comment: I guess you want S to start off being the set of row vectors of F.

Comment: Starting with S as the empty set seems right to me.  Also a quick comment about the original question:  In the case of real Hadamard matrices it's not hard to generate very small sets of pairwise orthogonal rows to which it is not possible to add additional orthogonal rows having only elements from the set {1,-1}.  For example, form the Kronecker product of a 4x4 Hadamard matrix with an all-one row vector of odd length.  It is impossible to add a fifth row to this matrix.  I'm fairly sure, however, that this is not relevant to the complex case.

Comment: Thanks, Will, I missed the movement up to the first paragraph of the requirement on $x$. 

Comment: I think it's best to demonstrate this difficulty by writing a computer program that tries to add such orthogonal rows randomly for a given dimension, and record the statistics at which d no new row can be found anymore. The fact that CHM's are hard to find is known, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The circulant matrix $G$ with $3$ rows, $8$ columns
and with first row

\begin{equation*}
G=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
satisfies

(1)
$$
GG^{T} = 8I,
$$

(2)

All entries in $G$ are $-1$ or $1$,

(3)

The only solution to: $XG=0$ is $X=0.$

Thus, 
 there is no unit vector with $XG=0.$

Comment: I am suspicious of the claim XG = 0.  However, even if it holds, the problem is to show that one cannot find a complex unit vector X in C^8 with GX = 0.  Given the degree of freedom in such a system, I suspect X exists.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.01.17

Comment: excuse me, I need to clarify: I am suspicious of the claim XG =0 implies X = 0.  Gerhard "Know What Your Suspicions Are" Paseman, 2011.01.17

Comment: Just do the computation ! Observe that we have only $3$ unknowns here
(say $x,y,z$ ), we get quickly $x=0,y=0,z=0.$

Comment: $X$ is assumed above to be a matrix with $1$ line and $3$ columns only.

Comment: Doesn't the OP really want that the only solution to $Gx=0$  is $x=0$, where $x$ is a vector with all unit entries? Matrices don't commute.

Comment: @Peter: You are right, the `answer` does NOT answer the OP question.
However, the result stated is OK and not immediate to find...

Comment: With 4 rows counts as well, and if the permutation is not cycling the 8 indices but the first 7, also with 7 rows and one can add an 8th row with 8th entry 1 and the rest -1. So this is not a good example